# Facebook API: upload video to page

Tags: .net, facebook

I'm trying to post a video to a Facebook page through the API (I'm using Facebook .NET SDK) and when I post to a profile everything goes ok but when I post to a page I get an exception:

> (190) Impersonated access tokens can only be used with the Graph API

According to [this](https://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/498/) it should be possible... I think it's more about API "theory" but just in case here is my code:

```
        Dim fbMedia As New FacebookMediaObject()

        fbMedia.FileName = System.IO.Path.GetFileName(txtFoto.Text)
        fbMedia.ContentType = "video/avi"

        fbMedia.SetValue(System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(txtFoto.Text))

        parameters.Add("method", "video.upload")
        parameters.Add("source", fbMedia)
        parameters.Add("caption", txtMensaje.Text)

        result = CType(fb.Post(parameters), IDictionary(Of String, Object))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the error message 'impersonated' means 'from a page' - you're trying to use the page access token with the deprecated REST API - you should be using the Graph API if you're using a Page Access Token

See the documentation here: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/page/#videos

I think the only modifications you'd need to make to your code are removing the 'method' parameter and making the API call to https://graph-video.facebook.com/PAGE_ID/videos instead of https://api.facebook.com/ (your SDK may handle this part for you once it detects you're using the current API and not the old REST API

Comment: I didn't have the time to test completely but look like the solution is as you say, but I need to use a _page token_, if not, the video get posted in page but the poster is not the page itself but the person. But when posting with page token I get a time out, so when I have time I will do more tests on that direction